# Editable feature service isn't appearing among editable layers list in Experience Builder Edit Data widget

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-experience-builder

I've gone through several tutorials on configuring the Edit Data widget in Esri's Experience Builder (example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hks65COYkGk)), but my feature service still isn't appearing among the list of editable layers when I try to configure the widget.

When I link the table widget to the same data source, the "Allow editing" checkbox is also absent from the Configure fields section of the data configuration window (min. ~5 in the tutorial above). As far as I can tell, the editability settings simply aren't updating in the Experience Builder application. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the feature layer you are attempting to edit inside of your map or added as an independent data source in the experience? Are you attempting to edit just attribute data or attribute and geometry data? Have you attempted to remove the layer from the data tab in Experience Builder and re-add it after updating the editing options?